# An ACT test question: " Which choice offers the most specific information about the method applied by some octopuses? "

Tags: exam-questions

> While one octopus might use trial-and-error to unlatch the cubes, another octopus may just **use a lot of strength in opening the larger cubes.**
>
> Which choice offers the most specific information about the method applied by some octopuses?
>
> F. NO CHANGE
> G. focus on the cubes themselves (instead of the latches)
> H. opt to break the larger cubes
> J. ruin the larger cubes

I think no one is better than the other to "offers the most specific information about the method applied by some octopuses" as all of them mention how the octopuses need to break the larger one.

The correct one is H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose "G" as the best answer.  The introductory sentence contrasts two different methods used to separate the cubes.  The first is opening the latches holding them together and the second is simply pulling the block apart until they separate.

Choice "G" is the only answer that mentions both approaches which are quite different.  For that reason, I consider it to be the best answer.

Comment: but the correct on is H

Comment: The question does not ask which choice offers the most *correct* information, it asks which choice is most *specific*. Of course the problem is that the most specific may not be correct. This shows the lack of thought that goes into these questions.  H is not correct because the passage says nothing to the effect that using strength actually causing the cubes to break. However I agree that H is the most *specific* answer but I still think it is inaccurate. Conclusion: Most examiners are stupid.

Comment: I disagree that "H" is in any way the correct answer.  But I'm just an observer.